# Modifying code during a debugging session.

Tags: debugging, programming-languages, ide, reverse-debugging

Does anyone know of a Debugger or Programming Language that allows you to set a break point,  and then modify the code and then execute the newly modified code.

This is even more useful if the Debugger also had the ability for [reverse debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html).  So you could step though the buggy code,  stack backwards, fix the code, and then step though it again to see if you fixed the bug.  Now that's sexy,  is anyone doing this?

Comment: It may be possible to do this for x86 assembly language in Visual Studio 2010. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556286/edit-assembly-language-code-in-visual-studio-while-stepping-through-each-stateme/15556693?noredirect=1#15556693

Comment: You should add a "live-programming" tag, as that is what propagation of changes in a live program is called - see my thesis, referenced in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Hot Code Replace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) in eclipse is what you meant in the problem:

> The idea is that you can start a debugging session on a given runtime
>   workbench and change a Java file in your development workbench, and
>   the debugger will replace the code in the receiving VM while it is
>   running. No restart is required, hence the reference to "hot".

But there are limitations:

> HCR only works when the class signature does not change; you cannot
>   remove or add fields to existing classes, for instance. However, HCR
>   can be used to change the body of a method.

Answer (score 2):

The [totalview](/questions/tagged/totalview) debugger provides the concept of *Evaluation Point* which allows user to "fix his code on the fly" or to "patch it" or to examine *what if* scenario without having to recompile.

Basically, user plants an *Evaluation Point* at some line and writes a piece of C/C++ or Fortran code he wants to execute instead. Could be a simple `printf`, `goto`, a set of `if`-`then`-`else` tests, some `for` loops etc... This is really powerful and time-sparing.

As for [reverse-debugging](/questions/tagged/reverse-debugging), it's a highly desirable feature, but I'm not sure it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The link is for VS 2005 but applies to 2008 and 2010 as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit, 2015: Read chapters 1 and 2 of my MSc thesis, [*Combining reverse debugging and live programming towards visual thinking in computer programming*](http://hdl.handle.net/10019.1/96853), it answers the question in detail.**

The Python debugger, Pdb, allows you to run arbitrary code while paused (like at a breakpoint). For example, let's say you are debugging and have paused at the following line in your program, where the variable hasn't been declared in the program itself :

```py
print (x)
```

so that moving forward (i.e., running that line) would result in :

```py
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

You can define that variable in the debugger, and have the program continue executing with it :

```py
(Pdb) 'x' in locals()
False
(Pdb) x = 1
(Pdb) 'x' in locals()
True
```

If you meant that the change should not be provided at the debugger console, but that you want to change the original code in some editor, then have the debugger automatically update the state of the live program in some way, so that the executing program reflects that change, that is called "live programming". (Not to be confused with "live coding" which is live performance of coding -- see [TOPLAP](http://toplap.org/) -- though there is some confusion.) There has been an interest in research into live programming (and live coding) in the last 2 or 3 years. It is a very difficult problem to solve, and there are many different approaches. You can watch Bret Victor's talk, [Inventing on Principle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUv66718DII), for some examples of that. Note that those are prototypes only, to illustrate the idea. Hot-swapping of code so that the tree is drawn differently in the next loop of some draw() function, or so that the game character responds differently next time, (or so that the music or visuals are changed during a live coding session), is not that difficult, some languages and systems cater for that explicitly. However, the state of the program is not necessarily then a true reflection of the code (as also in the Pdb example above) -- if e.g. the game character could access an area based on some ability like jumping, and the code is then swapped out, he might never be able to access that area in the game any longer *should the game be played from the start*. To solve change propagation for general programming is difficult -- you can see that his search example re-runs the code from the start each time a change is made.

True reverse execution is also a tricky problem. There are a number of commercial projects, but almost all of them only record trace data to browse it afterwards, called omniscient debugging (but they are often called reverse-, back-in-time, bidirectional- or time-travel-debuggers, also a lot of confusion). In terms of free and open-source projects, the GNU debugger, gdb, has two modes, one is [process record and replay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUv66718DII) which also only records the program for browsing it afterwards, the other is true [reverse debugging](http://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/Diplomarbeiten/sabin11.pdf) which allows you to reverse in a live program. It is extremely slow, as it undoes single machine instruction at a time. The extended python debugger prototype, epdb, also allows for true reversing in a live program, and is much faster as it uses a snapshot/checkpoint and replay mechanism. Here is the [thesis](http://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/Diplomarbeiten/sabin11.pdf) and here is the [program and the code](http://code.google.com/p/epdb/).