# Edit assembly language code in Visual Studio while stepping through each statement

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86, livecoding

In Visual Studio, is it possible to edit assembly language code while stepping through each statement (so that statements in the program can be modified while the program is running?) It would be useful to modify statements in a program while the program is running (for debugging purposes), but I'm not sure if this is possible yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the source code, but it doesn't get reassembled to produce  a new binary during your debugging session.  The debugger will tell you the "source no longer matches the code" but you can still step.  Your display may be confusing because, well, the source code no longer matches the object code :-}    I often add comments to instructions or in blank lines, which gets me the complaint, but you can still single-step and see the right source lines in this special case.

I think you can manually modify the memory containing the instruction you want to patch.   I've not ever bothered to do this; its easier to set a breakpoint where I'm at, re-assemble, and then run till the breakpoint.

You can modify all the registers and data memory pretty easily (actually you have to use this to modify the code memory, I think!).

A really useful thing to do is "Set Next Statement" to set the PC back to a somewhat earlier place in the code; you can often then step forward to point of failure, if the registers and memory aren't changed. (put cursor in your source or disassembly window, click on a line, then right-click "Set Next Statement")